# Why do I get "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'output' with dtype int64"?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a C++ program that reads a pre-trained model and uses it. I took the code [from here](https://medium.com/jim-fleming/loading-a-tensorflow-graph-with-the-c-api-4caaff88463f#.rzskqmq5z) and modified it a little bit.
What I have now is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Initialize a tensorflow session
  Session* session;
  Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Read in the protobuf graph we exported
  GraphDef graph_def;
  status = ReadTextProto(Env::Default(), "models/train.pbtxt", &graph_def);
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Add the graph to the session
  status = session->Create(graph_def);
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";
    return 1;
  }

  tensorflow::Tensor inputs(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({46}));
  auto inputs_flat = inputs.flat<float>();
  inputs_flat.setRandom();

  // The session will initialize the outputs
  std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

  status = session->Run({{"input", inputs}}, {"output"}, {}, &outputs);
  if (!status.ok()) {
    std::cout << status.ToString() << "\n";  // <--- error shows here
    return 1;
  }

  // Grab the first output
  // and convert the node to a scalar representation.
  auto output_c = outputs[0].scalar<int>();

  // Print the results
  std::cout << outputs[0].DebugString() << "\n";
  std::cout << output_c() << "\n";

  // Free any resources used by the session
  session->Close();
  return 0;
}
```

But when I run it, I get

```
Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'output' with dtype int64
     [[Node: output = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[[-1]], dtype=DT_INT64, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The graph I'm reading in `models/train.pbtxt` has 14K lines, so I am not copying it here. I'll put the relevant parts:

```
...................
node {
  name: "input"
  op: "Placeholder"
  attr {
    key: "_output_shapes"
    value {
      list {
        shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
          dim {
            size: 46
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_FLOAT
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "shape"
    value {
      shape {
      }
    }
  }
}
node {
  name: "output"
  op: "Placeholder"
  attr {
    key: "_output_shapes"
    value {
      list {
        shape {
          dim {
            size: -1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
      type: DT_INT64
    }
  }
  attr {
    key: "shape"
    value {
      shape {
      }
    }
  }
}
...................
```

So reads the question: what is this error message telling me?

Comment: It looks like this tensorflow library is expecting an output variable passed to the `Run` call's output node?

Comment: Maybe, but how? The examples I saw work like this one. There is another one here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/public

Answer (score 2):

In the original graph, there is a node named `"output"` that is a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders#placeholder), i.e. a symbolic tensor that must be [fed](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/reading_data/#feeding) when you run any operations that depend on it.

In the following line, which calls [`session->Run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/session#classtensorflow_1_1_session_1a8e3dd1ea08fe770eb78b86638d75bb5d), you are telling TensorFlow to evaluate and fetch the result of a node named `"output"`:

```
status = session->Run({{"input", inputs}}, {"output"}, {}, &outputs);
```

This doesn't seem to make sense: why fetch the value of a placeholder that must be fed on the same line?

I suspect that the node named `"output"` does not actually correspond to the output of your model (e.g. a prediction), but rather is a placeholder for feeding in the expected output (e.g. a known label for the corresponding value fed to `"input"`). There is probably some other node in the graph that you can evaluate to get the predictions, but its name will depend on how you originally constructed the graph.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the "real" output node. I generated it in python with an instance of `tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier` by using the method `fit`. After the question, I read that I should freeze the graph, but I couldn't do it. I could with the `freeze_graph` tool but for a graph constructed with TF r0.11, but not with r0.12, though.